# What is the equivalent of JS new map() on C#

Tags: dictionary

I've got on JS:
const something = new Map();

Something.set(smth)
And then something.get(smth)

can anybody provide an exact definition of it on C#? thanku!

Comment: You can use the Dictionary Class in C#
 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=net-5.0

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks! What type of data do I need if I got something like this,

```
Number = 123 
var userInfo = new { 
Name = name, Model = Model 
} 
MyDict.Add(Number, userInfo);
```

then foreach(KeyValuePair<int, object??> item in MyDict)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).